# make playing different buttons

Tags: android, media-player, playback

Suppose I have 3 buttons to play a sound, I want that if you press a button only plays a sound so I used this:

```
MediaPlayer mpButton1,mpButton2,mpButton3;

Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() { 

       public void onClick(View v){



       if( mpButton1 != null &&  mpButton1.isPlaying()){
           mpButton1.stop();
        }
       if( mpButton2 != null &&  mpButton2.isPlaying()){
           mpButton2.stop();
        }
       if( mpButton3 != null &&  mpButton3.isPlaying()){
           mpButton3.stop();
        }









       mpButton1 = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.b1);
         mpButton1.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mpButton1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                mpButton1.start();

                mpButton1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mpButton1) {
                        mpButton1.release();

                    };
                });
                    }
                });

    }});

Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
b2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() { 

               public void onClick(View v){

                   if( mpButton1 != null &&  mpButton1.isPlaying()){
                       mpButton1.stop();
                    }
                   if( mpButton2 != null &&  mpButton2.isPlaying()){
                       mpButton2.stop();
                    }
                   if( mpButton3 != null &&  mpButton3.isPlaying()){
                       mpButton3.stop();
                    }

                   mpButton2 = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.b2);
                     mpButton2.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mpButton2) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            mpButton2.start();

                            mpButton2.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mpButton2) {
                                    mpButton2.release();

                                };
                            });
                                }
                            });

               }});
```

// other 2 buttons the same with other sounds
I have tried various ways to do this, for example, by removing the release of the sound, but all give me a problem in the logcat when you call the button above, you starts with some idea to do this? thanks in advance

Logcat:

```
12-06 18:18:05.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27089): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 18:18:05.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27089): java.lang.IllegalStateException
12-06 18:18:05.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27089):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
12-06 18:18:05.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27089):    at org.bizzsound1.menu$3.onClick(menu.java:235)
12-06 18:18:05.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27089):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
12-06 18:18:05.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27089):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
12-06 18:18:05.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27089):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-06 18:18:05.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27089):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-06 18:18:05.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27089):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-06 18:18:05.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27089):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
12-06 18:18:05.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27089):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 18:18:05.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27089):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-06 18:18:05.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27089):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
12-06 18:18:05.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27089):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
12-06 18:18:05.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27089):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is there a `Caused by` further down the log?

Comment: no there is nothing more I'm sorry

Comment: the problem is that by starting this method, the condition requires that the previous sound should play to hear the new one .. but how is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're only telling mpButton1 to start playing AFTER you've checked to see if it's playing.

It's crashing because you're releasing the mediaplayers as soon as they've finished playing. This sets them back to null. This means when you call them the second time around, they return null and hence the app crashes. Remove the release method, do the following:

Move:

```
    mpButton1 = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.b1);
    mpButton2 = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.b2);
    mpButton3 = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.b3);
```

Into the onCreate or onResume method of your activity.

Comment: Yes I saw that, what I meant was did you actually do 
'mpButton2 = MediaPlayer.create'
etc. 
But I see underneath you said you did that.

Comment: The Android Documentation says "IllegalStateException if the internal player engine has not been initialized or has been released." This means every time you release you're button, it returns null. This is why it works when you take out the release method.

Comment: I had already tried and gives me the same error I'm going crazy: (

Comment: when to move them as you did the buttons do not sound

Comment: if I remove the release will give me this problem mediaplayer error (-19, 0)